# Import File in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here"s an Error I have and I can't solve:

Cannot import name "File" from 'uploadapp.models'

The code below makes it better to understand.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
from django.db import models
from .models import File

class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name
```

Comment: Look at the second import of your file. What are you importing exactly?

Comment: Please update your answer with your code, instead of attaching image. Few issues are it decreases readability, we can't copy paste from image, etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO! First of all, don't put images of code in your question, just copy&paste your code here, using proper formatting. Please read [ask] to learn how to. Second: you can't import `File` inside the file where you define it. Remove the `from .models import File`.

Comment: @MilesDavis I am actually using a class named "File" in my models.py.

And also trying to important that "File" in my models.py

Comment: From where do you want to import that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Circular dependency**

---

You're trying to import `File` from `models.py` in `models.py` file.

Reference: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm